# About Amazon Advertising Api

Tags: api

I applied for the use of the Amazon advertising API, but when I created a security profile in the console, I could use the advertising API of the North American station but not the European station. Do I need to resubmit the application form? url returns an unknown scope

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope` header value which is tied to the EU seller or vendor account.

> 1. Use profile endpoint and fetch all profiles which are tied to your current token.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/profiles' \
--header 'Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId: amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer Atza|xxxxxxxxx'
```

Response:

```
 {
        "profileId": 390000000000000000,
        "countryCode": "US",
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "dailyBudget": 0.0,
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "accountInfo": {
            "marketplaceStringId": "AXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "id": "BXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "seller"
        }
    },
```

You can see NA(North America) profiles(marketplaces) using this request above. In order to retrieve the EU or FE region profiles(marketplaces), Change the API endpoint.

```
EU = https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles
FE = https://advertising-api-fe.amazon.com/v2/profiles
```

2. Use `profileId` property in `Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope` header(This header is required. see documentation) for all API requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed the request url and host, and successfully got the refresh_token, but I still only got the North American account ID (us and ca) when I got my profile.

Comment: Is this token tied to your amazon seller account? Can you verify this seller account has EU markets as well in seller central UI(ad console)?

Comment: When I construct the url, it will return an+unknown+scope+was+requested

Comment: post your request as curl format or whatever you are familiar.